# pyinstaller ImportError: DLL load failed - only on some PC's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have created an exe using pyinstaller by running the following command:

```
pyinstaller app_proto.spec
```

app_proto.spec is shown below :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['app_proto.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:/Users/user01/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/dask/dask.yaml', 'dask' )],
             hiddenimports=['dask'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='app_proto',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )


a.datas +=[('./icons/application-export.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\application-export.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/application-import.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\application-import.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/application-wave.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\application-wave.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/arrow-out.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\arrow-out.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/border-bottom-thick.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\border-bottom-thick.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/border-left.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\border-left.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/border-right.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\border-right.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/chart--plus.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\chart--plus.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/desktop.ini','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\desktop.ini','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/edit-list-rtl.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\edit-list-rtl.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/folder-open-document.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\folder-open-document.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/marker.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\marker.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/minus-circle.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\minus-circle.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/minus.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\minus.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/report-word.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\report-word.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/script-attribute-y.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\script-attribute-y.png','DATA')]
a.datas +=[('./icons/system-monitor.png','C:\\Users\\user01\\Documents\\GitHub Repos\\app\\src\\icons\\system-monitor.png','DATA')]

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='app_proto')
```

On some PCs when running the exe using `--onedir` mode with debug enabled the following output is presented:

```
[2020] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
[2020] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mpldata.py
[2020] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pyqt5.py
[2020] LOADER: Running app_proto.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\app_proto.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user01\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "src\pyinstallerimports\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user01\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\cchardet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cchardet: The specified module could not be found.
[2020] Failed to execute script app_proto
[2020] LOADER: OK.
[2020] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

As mentioned in the question the exe works on a handful of PCs (some that have never had python on before - if that matters).
**Within the directory of the exe there is a folder named `cchardet` with the .pyd file `_cchardet`**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error with **cchardet** while using **Python 3.7**. Updating Visual C++ solved this for me.
Try these steps -

1. download x64: vc_redist.x64.exe from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
2. Install it.
3. Restart your computer